# I am seeking advice for a general audience expository journal

Tags: advice

Prefatory note: This be off-topic for this site and, if so, I apologize and seek direction.  I am seeking advice for a general audience expository journal to submit my article, “An Application of a Space-Filling Curve to General Orthogonal Polynomials.” This is a purely theoretical application of a space-filling curve (as opposed to practical applications, e.g., in data storage and retrieval).  I originally published this as a lemma toward a larger theorem in a specialized technical journal in 1988.  However, that lemma was so “buried” in that article that this curious application of a space-filling curve never received the attention of a more general audience, which has been my objective in seeking to publish this new article.  I have received editorial and reviewer feedback that the article is well-written and interesting.